# I am able to output almost all the XML element contents into a table except the value of (Local ="No")

Tags: xml, xslt, element

I am a trying to write an xsl code for the folling xml code, and so far i am able to output almost all the element contents into a table except the value of (Local ="No") which is in the food element tag. Is there a way to output that attribute and its value. Thank you.

```
 <FoodItems>
        <food   Local = "No" >
            <Name>Rice</Name>
            <Brand>Jasmine</Brand>
            <Price>$89</price>
            <Grade>A</grade>
        </food> 
    </FoodItems>
```

Comment: The relative path depends on the context. The absolute path in your example would be `/FoodItems/food/@Local`.

Comment: Problem resolved, Thanks to you.

Comment: I just discovered that i had missed one aspect of its implementation. The code given to me works just fine but now having problems displaying different values based on the different food items. i am sure i am missing something, but do not know what it is. i just began learning xml. Again thanks for your help. i wonder how i could get it to output different values based on its different food items.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your existing XSLT and the expected result.

Comment: And of course the XML with multiple food items.

Comment: And say how tasty each of the food is.